# rpy2: How many instances of R are running?

Tags: python, rpy2

If I start up multiple threads in a single python program that all use rpy2, will they be communicating with the same instance of R?  What if I have multiple separate python processes running that do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to the first question. No to the second. One instance of R per process.